# Как можно получить доступ к данным React компонента с помощью скриптов

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, браузер, web-scraping

Есть сайт, который работает на `React`. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ скриптом (`Python`, `JS` язык особо не важен) забрать данные из `props` одного компонента. Пока нашел способ получить доступ к этим данным только через `React DevTools` из `Chrome`. Может сам `React` позволяет как-то получить доступ к компонентам?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто. Данные реакта хранятся в доме элемента, к которому они прикреплены в поле `"__reactInternalInstance$......."`. Путешествуя по объекту в консоли хрома так и не понял где находятся `props` компонента. Но нашел нужное свойство просто по имени, пробежав рекурсивно по всему объекту.